# How to retrieve a single 7zip file without extracting all of it in Python3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, compression, 7zip, directory-listing

In Python, I want to browse all the sub directories in and only selectively extract a 7z file after checking its content. I do not want to extract all the files but I should be able to peep into the content iteratively/ recursively.

The main concern is the .7z zip is of size 15 GB but when it is unzipped it is 225 GB. Now my hard disk is 160 GB. Of those 225 GB I might need only valid 60 GB data. I can search for that only if I can go through the data in the individual file. Is there any os.walk kind of function on .7z file ?

`https://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/static_html_dumps/current/en/*.7z` is the file, I am exploring.

```
7z l *.7z

7-Zip [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21
p7zip Version 16.02 (locale=C.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,4 CPUs Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6300U CPU @ 2.40GHz (406E3),ASM,AES-NI)

Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 15363543213 bytes (15 GiB)

Listing archive: wikipedia-en-html.tar.7z

--
Path = wikipedia-en-html.tar.7z
Type = 7z
Physical Size = 15363543213
Headers Size = 100
Method = LZMA:22
Solid = -
Blocks = 1

   Date      Time    Attr         Size   Compressed  Name
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
2008-06-18 23:32:15 ..... 223674511360  15363543113  wikipedia-en-html.tar
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
2008-06-18 23:32:15       223674511360  15363543113  1 files
```

```
import lzma

f7file = r"C:\Users\padmaraj.bhat\OneDrive - Accenture\Downloads\wiki-html\wikipedia-en-html.tar.7z"

f = lzma.open(f7file, 'rb')
for line in f:
    lzma.decompress(line)
    break
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
  <ipython-input-5-d1a496a0c194> in <module>()
      4 
      5 f = lzma.open(f7file, 'rb')
----> 6 for line in f:
      7     lzma.decompress(line)
      8     break

  ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\lzma.py in readline(self, size)
    220         """
    221         self._check_can_read()
--> 222         return self._buffer.readline(size)
    223 
    224     def write(self, data):

  ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\_compression.py in readinto(self, b)
     66     def readinto(self, b):
     67         with memoryview(b) as view, view.cast("B") as byte_view:
---> 68             data = self.read(len(byte_view))
     69             byte_view[:len(data)] = data
     70         return len(data)

  ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\_compression.py in read(self, size)
    101                 else:
    102                     rawblock = b""
--> 103                 data = self._decompressor.decompress(rawblock, size)
    104             if data:
    105                 break

LZMAError: Input format not supported by decoder
```

Comment: The error message suggests that your file is not a proper `lzma` compressed file, so the Python `lzma` module chokes on it. That's not something we can really help you diagnose or fix, as it has nothing to do with your code, and everything to do with how you got the file (which may have used code, but not anything you've shown us). Your code and its issue also don't seem to have a great deal to do with your question title and text, which refer to your desire to explore folder structure that doesn't seem to exist anywhere in your code at all.

Comment: 7zip is a compressed *archive* format, not a single file compressor. It uses LZMA to compress the members of the archive, but the archive itself is not an LZMA/XZ file. There is no Python built-in module for decompressing 7zip files. You might want to look at [`libarchive`, a third party module which claims to support 7zip](https://pypi.org/project/libarchive/).

Comment: @ShadowRanger: I did try with libarchive. The built itself fails. I also tried libarchive-c, here build is successful but import of it fails.

Comment: @Blckknght : is there any 'uncompress a single file, browse it and forget it' tack ticks available ? I dont want to unzip all files and save it in my hard disk. Unzipping a single file would require minimal RAM usage and 'forgetting it' saves a lot of hard disk space. As if to peak into the zipfile and leave it as is.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I have modified the problem statement for the actual problem; let me know if it has narrowed the space of research.

Answer (score 2):

When I had to do something like that, I had to call the `7z` CLI via `subprocess()`. In this way, you can determine file lists as well as file contents from the archive.

For example, for extracting files directly to stdout, you can use [the `-so` option](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/stdout.htm).

Comment: I guess it would fail because it would to uncompress it first and then avail the details. If open in windows , the zip file fails indicating I dont have enough hard disk space.

Comment: @PadmarajBhat No. There are dedicated CLI commands for listing an archive directory and for getting a file out of the archive. AFAIR, the latter can be done directly to stdout.

Comment: @PadmarajBhat, zip files have an index allowing readers to seek directly to the location of the compressed stream storing a single file; they don't need to be decompressed in full before files can be listed or before a single file can be extracted (including to stdout). Thus, streaming the file list and/or an individual's file contents is an appropriate solution to your problem.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy If I think aout it again, then it could be that with "solid archives" (not sure if that's the correct term with 7z), things could be different. That should be tested.

Comment: @glglgl I guess I would need the bigger hard disk. I have listed the 7z file details. If I understand the details correctly, the .7z file is a zip on a .tar file. The tar file must have been 200gb and 7z must have compressed it to 15gb. There may be n such layers but I guess it would not be feasible to peep into the inner ones unless we unzip the outer ones.....pls let me know your views here.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy [From my analysis mentioned prior to this comment ] Is there any way we can recursively seek ?

Comment: @PadmarajBhat, it's always feasible, depending on how much work you're willing to do. Even if the file format isn't innately seekable, you can do a multi-pass approach, building an index on the first pass (retaining compression-table state at points of interest) and using it again later.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Any reference material regarding that would help me a lot. I am willing to go few more steps at least.

Comment: @PadmarajBhat As I noted, there is an option to pipe a file to stdout. So instead of saving it, you should be ble to pipe that into a different program such as tar and then just extract/process/… only certain files.

Comment: Looking at [the Python gzip module](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/gzip.py) for inspiration is a good place to start. If each layer returns a file-like object that implements the necessary interfaces, and doesn't depend on things like `fileno()` that only work with a real file, you can nest them as deep as you like. For the more advanced bits, like parsing the zip footer (if there is one in 7z vs upstream zip) for offsets, you'll want to look at tools implementing similar interfaces for similar formats.